# Merge tags [pwa] and [progressive-web-apps]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

[pwa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pwa) ▷ 163 questions

[progressive-web-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/progressive-web-apps) ▷ 983 questions

They are synonyms. The former is an acronym for the latter. Should they be merged?